# Binding data to a ToolStripComboBox

Tags: c#, data-binding

**C#**

I have `ToolStripComboBox` control. Is there a way to bind this `ToolStripComboBox` to a list?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

try

```
List<string> items = new List<string>{"item1", "item2", "item3"};
toolStripComboBox1.ComboBox.DataSource = items;
```

Comment: Thank you :) I missed the .ComboBox. part

Comment: I tried this before finding your post, but for me I still see no entries in the ComboBox, while the DataSource is set.

Comment: ComboBox is not a property that is listed in the WinForms designer but it is available programmatically

Comment: Also set the BindingContext as per @dAngelo's answer.

Answer (score 11):

You might also need to set ComboBox.BindingContext to Form's BindingContext property:

```
toolStripComboBox1.ComboBox.BindingContext = this.BindingContext;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're finding this and you want the ComboBox to dynamically you'll need to make sure that the data structure that you have set as the Data Source implements [IBindingList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.ibindinglist%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) one such structure is [BindingList(T)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132679%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)