# Proper Syntax For Toolbar Combobox

Tags: c#

I'm writing some toolbar code for a window in the NinjaTrader application.  I have buttons running quite well but cannot figure out the proper syntax for implementing a combobox.  Here is the syntax of for the buttons;

**Declare the variable-------**

```
private System.Windows.Forms.ToolStrip strip = null;
private System.Windows.Forms.Control[] controls    = null;
private System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripButton btnHalt = null;
```

**Initialize the button--------**

```
ToolStripButton btnTemp = new System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripButton("temp");
boldFont = new Font("Arial", 8,FontStyle.Bold);
regularFont = new Font("Arial", 8);
btnTemp = null;

btnHalt = new System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripButton("btnHalt");
btnManual.Font = boldFont;
btnHalt.Font = regularFont;   
btnHalt.ForeColor = Color.White;
btnHalt.BackColor = Color.Red;   
btnHalt.Text = "Trading Off";
strip = (System.Windows.Forms.ToolStrip)controls[0];
strip.Items.Add(btnHalt);
btnHalt.Click += btnHalt_Click;
```

**Cleanup the toolbar--------**

```
public override void Dispose() 
{
    if (buttonsloaded==true)
    {
        strip.Items.Remove(btnHalt);
    }
}
```

**On_Click Event Code---------**

```
private void btnHalt_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (btnHalt.Text == "Trading Off")
    {
        btnHalt.Text = "Trading On";
        btnHalt.Font = regularFont;
        btnHalt.ForeColor = Color.White;
        btnHalt.BackColor = Color.Green;
    }
}
```

If anyone can show me the proper syntax for a combobox I would really appreciate it!

Thank you in advance!

Comment: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/6ad35c1b-5b35-4f94-8570-59a9be6b4ad9/toolstripcombobox-adding-items?forum=winforms

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5848982/binding-data-to-a-toolstripcombobox

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.toolstripcombobox%28v=vs.110%29.aspx