# Looking for a windows form control

Tags: winforms

I have a windows forms app (I don't have access to the source code) which has a control that looks like this:

[image]

On clicking the down arrow, the popup appears from which I can select.

Is this a standard control that I can use, if so which one is it?

If not, then what control comes closest to it?

Comment: Looks like a ContextMenu - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa984254(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: ContextMenu controls are usually stand-alone, and triggered by a right-click on something.  The look of that arrow button suggests a ComboBox control.

Comment: Add a ToolStrip first.  Then add a DropDownButton to the strip, add its menu entries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [@Hans Passant](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17034/hans-passant) mentioned you can simply add a DropDown to a ComboBox.
[Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.toolstripcombobox(v=vs.110).aspx) is a example from MSDN. If you dont want to do the whole thing prgramaticaly just add the controls manualy and check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5848982/binding-data-to-a-toolstripcombobox) to see how the databinding works.